# Sed replace ">" to "/>" bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I'm newbie and I would like to replace "special" caracters with sed. I have an xml file that it is not  well formed and at the end of any data row it finish with ">" I need to scrap it and to do it I need to change ">" with "/>". But when I try:

```
sed -i s/>//>/g FILE
```

returns => -bash: //: Is a directory

same with:

```
sed -i s/>/\/>/g FILE
```

also with

```
sed -i s,>,\>,g FILE
```

Man page doesn't solve this problem.

Does anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the slash character if you use it a separator:

```
sed 's/>/\/>/g'
```

Or use another character e.g.:

```
sed 's_>_/>_g'
```

Note that this will replace all matches in the file, not just the last one

If you want to match only `>` not preceded by `/`, you can use this:

```
sed -r 's_[^/]>_/>_g' file
```

Comment: Hi, I tried both options but it says "sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command" with sed -i s_>_\>_g data.xml and sed -i s,>,\>,g data.xml

Comment: @MarcPursals You have the wrong slash. Try with a forward slash `/`. Also single quote the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Would sed -i 's/>$//>/g' FILE work for you?

```
$ echo "<blah> <blah>" | sed 's/>$/\/>/g'
<blah> <blah/>
```